# HTA: Javascript calculator - adding new variables

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, calculator

I'm a neurosurgeon trying to update a javascript calculator I made about four years ago. It takes a number of variables about an intracranial aneurysm and gives the estimated rupture rate based on three different cohort studies. I'm trying to include a new metaanalysis with more variables using the same approach. Unfortunately, when I add the new variables and if functions, the calculator breaks....

The original calculator works like this: http://www.timkilleen.com/calc1.html

```
<strong><large>Aneurysm Calculator - ISUIA</large></strong>
<br>
<br>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getRisk()
    {
        var size = window.document.getElementById('An_Size').value;
        var location = window.document.getElementById('locate').value;
        var ysah = window.document.getElementById('yessah');
        var nsah = window.document.getElementById('nosah');

        x=size;
        y=location;
            z=ysah.checked?"yes":"no";

   if( x==0         ) output(" -- / --")
               if( x>0&& x<7        && y=="ant" && z=="no"  ) output(" 1 /0 ")
if( x>=7&& x<12     && y=="ant" && z=="no"  ) output(" 0.9948 /2.6 ")
if( x>=12&&x<25     && y=="ant" && z=="no"  ) output(" 0.971 /14.5 ")
if( x>=25   && y=="ant" && z=="no"  ) output(" 0.92 /40 ")
if( x>0&& x<7       && y=="post"    && z=="no"  ) output(" 0.995 /2.5 ")
if( x>=7&& x<12     && y=="post"    && z=="no"  ) output(" 0.971 /14.5 ")
if( x>=12&&x<25     && y=="post"    && z=="no"  ) output(" 0.9632 /18.4 ")
if( x>=25   && y=="post"    && z=="no"  ) output(" 0.9 /50 ")
if( x>0&& x<7       && y=="int"     && z=="no"  ) output(" 1 /0 ")
if( x>=7&& x<12     && y=="int"     && z=="no"  ) output(" 1 /0 ")
if( x>=12&&x<25     && y=="int"     && z=="no"  ) output(" 0.994 /3 ")
if( x>=25   && y=="int"     && z=="no"  ) output(" 0.9872 /6.4 ")
if( x>0&& x<7       && y=="ant" && z=="yes"     ) output(" 0.997 /1.5 ")
if( x>=7&& x<12     && y=="ant" && z=="yes" ) output(" 0.9948 /2.6 ")
if( x>=12&&x<25     && y=="ant" && z=="yes"     ) output(" 0.971 /14.5 ")
if( x>=25   && y=="ant" && z=="yes"     ) output(" 0.92 /40 ")
if( x>0&& x<7       && y=="post"    && z=="yes"     ) output(" 0.9932 /3.4 ")
if( x>=7&& x<12     && y=="post"    && z=="yes"     ) output(" 0.971 /14.5 ")
if( x>=12&&x<25     && y=="post"    && z=="yes"     ) output(" 0.9632 /18.4 ")
if( x>=25   && y=="post"    && z=="yes"     ) output(" 0.9 /50")
if( x>0&& x<7       && y=="int"     && z=="yes"     ) output(" 1 /0 ")
if( x>7&& x<12      && y=="int"     && z=="yes"     ) output(" 1 /0 ")
if( x>=12&&x<25     && y=="int"     && z=="yes"     ) output(" 0.994 /3 ")
if( x>=25   && y=="int"     && z=="yes"     ) output(" 0.9872 /6.4 ")

    }

    function output(str)
    {
        var arr = str.split("/");
        var one_yr_risk = parseFloat(arr[0]);
        var life_expectancy = parseFloat(window.document.getElementById('life_expectancy').value);
        var cum_risk="--";
        var five_yr_risk="--"
        {
            five_yr_risk = arr[1];
            cum_risk = Math.round(((1-Math.pow((one_yr_risk), life_expectancy))*100)*10)/10;
        }
        window.document.getElementById('r2').value=five_yr_risk;    
        if(life_expectancy<10)
            cum_risk="--";

        if(cum_risk===0)
            cum_risk="0*";

        window.document.getElementById('r1').value=cum_risk;
    }

</script>

<img alt="" src="/sites/default/files/COW.gif" style="width: 250px; height: 284px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; margin: 0px;" />
<form action="" id="riskform" onSubmit="return false;">
   <fieldset>
    <label for="locate">Location</label>
    <select id="locate" name='locate'
    onchange="getRisk()">
    <option value="ant">Anterior circulation</option>
    <option value="post">Posterior circulation (incl. PCom)</option>
    <option value="int">Intracavernous</option>

   </select>
   <br>
<br>
    <p>
    <label class="inlinelabel" for='includeinscription'>
    Size(mm)</label>
    <input type="text"  id="An_Size" size=7 onKeyUp="getRisk()"
    name="size" value="0"  />
    </p>
    <label >Previous SAH?</label>
    <input type="radio"  name="prevsah" value="yessah" id="yessah"
    onclick="getRisk()" />
    Yes
    <input type="radio"  name="prevsah" value="nosah" id="nosah"
    onclick="getRisk()" />
    No
<br>
<br>    
<label for="Five_Year">5 Year Rupture Risk (%)</label>
<input type="text" name="val3" id="r2"><span id="result2"></span>
          <p>
<p>
<br>
    <label class="inlinelabel" for='includeinscription'>
    Estimated life expectancy (minimum 10 years)</label>
    <input type="text"  id="life_expectancy" size=7 onKeyUp="getRisk()"
    name="size" value="0"  />
    </p>

<label for="One_Year">Cumulative Lifetime Rupture Risk (%)</label>
<input type="text" name="val3" id="r1"><span id="result1"></span>

    <div id="Final_Risk"></div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I have added two new yes/no variables and an additional drop-down selection (ethnicity) which exponentially increased the size of the possible if functions (not included for brevity, example below).

```
if( x>=20           && y=="oth" && z=="no" && u=="yes" && v=="no" && w="jp"     ) output(" 0.9644 /17.8 ")
```

The new variables are set up as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getRisk()
    {
        var size = window.document.getElementById('An_Size').value;
        var location = window.document.getElementById('locate').value;
        var ysah = window.document.getElementById('yessah');
        var nsah = window.document.getElementById('nosah');
        var eth = window.document.getElementById('ethno').value;
        var osev = window.document.getElementById('oversev');
        var usev = window.document.getElementById('undersev');
        var yhtn = window.document.getElementById('yhyp');
        var nhtn = window.document.getElementById('nhyp');


        u=yhtn.checked?"yes":"no";
        v=osev.checked?"yes":"no";
        w=eth;
        x=size;
        y=location;
        z=ysah.checked?"yes":"no";
```

I'm pretty sure I've incorrectly implemented the additional variables and/or incorrectly set up the html form here:

```
   </select>
    </p>
    <label >Previous SAH?</label>
    <input type="radio"  name="prevsah" value="yessah" id="yessah"
    onclick="getRisk()" />
    Yes
    <input type="radio"  name="prevsah" value="nosah" id="nosah"
    onclick="getRisk()" />
    No
    <p>
    <label >Hypertension?</label>
    <input type="radio"  name="htn" value="yhyp" id="yhyp"
    onclick="getRisk()" />
    Yes
    <input type="radio"  name="htn" value="nhyp" id="nhyp"
    onclick="getRisk()" />
    No
    <p>
    <label >Age over 70?</label>
    <input type="radio"  name="oversev" value="osev" id="osev"
    onclick="getRisk()" />
    Yes
    <input type="radio"  name="oversev" value="usev" id="usev"
    onclick="getRisk()" />
    No
<br>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Best wishes,

Tim

Comment: New (broken) code: http://www.timkilleen.com/calc3.html

Comment: Original (working) code: http://www.timkilleen.com/calc1.html

Comment: Please [edit] and include the code in the question (Link is fine, but the code itself must be in the question body)

Comment: Please read about creating a [mcve], with emphasis on _minimal_ - You need to include only the relevant code and explain what's wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked your broken code. It's giving error on console. `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`. Try using `w=="jp"` instead of `w="jp"` for all your conditions.

And replace following

```
var osev = window.document.getElementById('oversev');
var usev = window.document.getElementById('undersev');
```

with

```
var osev = window.document.getElementById('osev');
var usev = window.document.getElementById('usev');
```

You are using wrong ids.

Comment: Yep - that definitely caused an improvement. I now get -- in each of the result boxes. Hopefully I can work it out from here..... Many thanks!!!

Comment: If that works please up vote the answer or let me know if any issues comes up after using the solution.

Comment: I've uploaded the new html to http://www.timkilleen.com/calc3.html with the corrections you suggested. Now the result it always -- (which it should be if only if x = 0). I think the problem may be due to the multiple yes/no radio button inputs....

Comment: You missed one condition `if( x>0&& x<7   && y=="ica" && z=="yes" && u=="yes" && v=="no" && w="jp" ) output(" 0.9974 /1.3 ")`